AWS DMS / Redshift target - data validation returns false positives
We recently enabled data validation on the Redshift target for our DMS tasks with ongoing replication (released Nov 2024 AWS DMS added support for Redshift target data validation). Shortly after we recorded over thousands of errors with failure type "RECORD_DIFF" (besides some others like date formatting in the target). The AWS support's feedback was "DMS failed to compare the source and target for the above column due to internal limitation on the function that is used for validation". Which doesn't offer any solution on how to resolve this. Is there a config/mapping rule that could help us to weed out the false positives and focus on troubleshooting only the true data errors? Or is data validation for Redshift as a target for DMS task in fact waste of computing power/money?
I only found one example (bellow) of the validation rule config and tested it to see if it resolves at least the NULL values error in the target but nothing related to mismatched data and how to validate those more precisely.  :
        {
            "rule-type": "validation",
            "rule-id": "1",
            "rule-name": "1",
            "rule-target": "column",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "test",
                "table-name": "%",
                "column-name": "%"
            },
            "rule-action": "override-validation-function",
            "source-function": "REPLACE(${column-name}, chr(0), chr(32))",
            "target-function": "${column-name}"
        }  


Check sys_query_history to see what the validation call is trying to do against redshift, or make a dead simple one column table and then add the other columns in until you match whatever table is failing to figure out what column type is the problem
